# How do you deal with nested namespaces in Savon?

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

If I have the following SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://test.org/" xmlns:hon="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TEST.RVU.Entity">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Authenticate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:authenticationDet>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hon:AccountType>0</hon:AccountType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hon:Password>bacon</hon:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hon:UserName>smith</hon:UserName>
         </tem:authenticationDet>
      </tem:Authenticate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do I write down a valid soap request using the Savon gem that includes the tem: and hon: namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the additional namespace.

The script could look like this:

```
#!ruby

require "savon"

Savon.configure do |c|
  c.pretty_print_xml = true
  c.env_namespace = :soapenv
end

client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.namespace = "http://test.org"
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://www.your-real-endpoint.com"
end

resp = client.request :tem, 'Authenticate' do
  soap.namespaces["xmlns:hon"] = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/08/TEST.RVU.Entity"
  soap.body = { "tem:authenticationDet" => 
                { "hon:AccountType" => 0,
                  "hon:Password" => "bacon",
                  "hon:UserName" => "smith" }
              }
end
```